# Why 'assert_not' and not '!' when writing Rails tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

Consider this example, we'd like to check whether it's allowed for user to have blank name (it shouldn't be):

```
test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
end
```

The question is why does `assert_not` exists? Wouldn't it be better if we just use `assert` like this:

```
test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = "     "
    assert !@user.valid?
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It likely exists to remove modifiers from your assertions, which may change their results or obscure what you're actually asking.  In reality, it's mostly a style choice.

It's kind of the same motivation for having `unless` in the language, instead of writing this:

```
if !@user.valid?
  # do stuff
end
```

You would do:

```
unless @user.valid?
  # do stuff
end
```

Granted, the if/unless differences read *way better* than `assert_not`, alas that's what Minitest unit tests are going to get you.  If you want things to read more naturally, take a look at Minitest specs or RSpec.